# Connect uploaded file to and sql ID

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I will try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I have an SQL database for members, the columns are ID NAME EMAIL and IP

I also have an image uploader so that members can upload the images to an upload folder.

I want to display the images that the member uppload in a table, ( Only the filename ) but I need it to connect to the member ID. So when the images is uploaded the table will look something like

ID | date | ImageName

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a "userId" column in your image SQL table.
When somebody upload a picture, add its Id to the INSERT INTO statement, with image filename.
Then when you want to display pictures from a user, just a simple query with a where clause will do the job.

Comment: Hmm, don't really get it. 
noob as I am :)